# How to fix the error when decompiling MCP 9.18?

Tags: java, minecraft, mcps

When I am decompiling the MCP 9.18 (For 1.8.8) to make a minecraft client I get an error. At the point of when it reached the recompiling process it gave me a massive error.

[image: pic from cmd prompt]

I think that the statement:

```
== ERRORS FOUND in JAVA CODE ==

error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later. 

error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.

==
```

Should help.

Comment: This is a bad solution but try using a predecompiled MCP . Also please don't use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) if you can paste the error message.

Comment: Sometimes predecompiled MCP also doesn't have some of the modules that it needs. It will show up another thousand of erros that there are no exisitng modules. If you can, can you please, sned me a link to the mcp that actually is fully decompiled (It's usually like a gigabyte or something). I could't find any.

Comment: https://github.com/ZeroedInOnTech/1.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encountered this error just before, go here:

`conf\mcp.cfg`

Open & edit the file, go to CmdRecomp, change values of `-source` & `-target` from `1.6` to `1.8`

Source and target must equal the same value. Chances are you will be using 1.8/Java 8, so use that instead of 1.7/Java 7 as the error says.

Comment: Now it gives another error :( :Copying assets... OK
Parsing JSON file... OK
Looking for minecraft main jar... OK
> Checking libraries...
        Copying library netty... Error copying library com.mojang:netty:1.7.7
Press any key to continue . . .